# Getting an instance to a XAML class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find the answer to this.

I have a WPF window called Popup (so I have Popup.Xaml, Popup.Xaml.cs).
Is there a way to determine if there is an active (visible) window instance of this class?
I need to check if the popup is currently visible and skip doing some actions in a different class (a class that has no UI control associated with it) if the Popup window is currently visible.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your Popup just create global variable `public static bool isPopupVisible = true` (for ex in App class). Then you must handled event closing Popup and changed `isPopupVisible = false`. And that's all. Only check this variable whenever you need.

Comment: @OSH, but my way - is not perfect. Did you try HighCore answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Application.Current.Windows.OfType<YourWindowType>().Any(x => x.IsActive))
{
   //... etc
}
```